# Android Drawable - Dynamic Color based on hex value

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable, android-drawable

I have pins that go on a map -

right now I am doing:

```
Drawable Marker_1 = null;
Drawable Marker_2 = null;
Drawable Marker_3 = null;
Drawable Marker_4 = null;
Drawable Marker_5 = null;
Drawable Marker_6 = null;
Drawable Marker_7 = null;
Drawable Marker_8 = null;
Drawable Marker_9 = null;
Drawable Marker_10 = null;
Drawable Marker_11 = null;
    Marker_2 = MA.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_00ff00);
    Marker_3 = MA.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_990099);
    Marker_4 = MA.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_ff0000);
    Marker_5 = MA.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_000000);
    Marker_6 = MA.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_ffffff);
    Marker_7 = MA.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_999999);
    Marker_8 = MA.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_ff9900);
    Marker_9 = MA.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_ffcccc);
    Marker_10 = MA.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_999966);
    Marker_11 = MA.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_cc99cc);
    houseMarker = MA.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.house_outline);
```

...

```
if (color.contains("ffffff")) {
        return houseMarker;
    } else if (color.contains("00ff00")) {
        return Marker_2;
    } else if (color.contains("990099")) {
        return Marker_3;
    } else if (color.contains("ff0000")) {
        return Marker_4;
    } else if (color.contains("000000")) {
        return Marker_5;
    } else if (color.contains("0000ff")) {
        return Marker_1;
    } else if (color.contains("999999")) {
        return Marker_7;
    } else if (color.contains("ff9900")) {
        return Marker_8;
    } else if (color.contains("ffcccc")) {
        return Marker_9;
    } else if (color.contains("999966")) {
        return Marker_10;
    } else if (color.contains("cc99cc")) {
        return Marker_11;
    }
```

I want to avoid this and be able to just have one marker (a white drawable) and then change the drawables color to what is passed in

Comment: how does the drawable look like? are they just solid colours?

Answer (score -1):

if it really is a color you should be able to use:

Drawable.setColorFilter( yourcolor, Mode.MULTIPLY )

This will take anything that is white and make it your color.  Anything clear should be ignored, and any other colors will just get their color tweaked.

I don't know why your colors are strings. You need to get them as hex values in an int.

So for your Marker_9, you would use 0xffffcccc, and for marker 10, you'd use 0xff999966, etc.